# Mobile browser initialising different width

Tags: html, css

So guys I have been working on a responsive website for some time now. I have the layout sorted now and also the content, so I decided to add breakpoints to the website and using media queries adjust the elements accordingly. So I know that breakpoints must be added based on when the layout starts to break and **not** on the   popular screen resolutions, but when I tested the website on the android version of Firefox on my Moto X(2013), my phone has a resolution of 1280x720 pixels but when I add a breakpoint at let's say 700 pixels using the min-width query, it doesn't affect the page but when I change the same query for a min-width of 980 pixels, it works. Now my question is: isn't it supposed to trigger on the actual resolution or do browsers render it differently? BTW I am talking about the portrait orientation.

Comment: set the viewport - remember!

Comment: I use the min-width and max- width media queries. Aren't these media queries related to the actual viewport than the device output area?

Answer (score 1):

Resolution is different of aspect ratio, I will recommended you include aspect ratio in you media queries to achieve your goal, see this video to understand differences between aspect ratio and resolutions

> [Resolution and Aspect Ratio Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npbsI8-nD-4)

You can build your media query like this:

```
    @media only screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 768px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
            .your_css_classes{}
    }
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks man, will consider it. Can you please tell me what the device-pixel-ratio media feature is?